# Storing fractional values in mifare cards

Tags: floating-point, fractions, mifare

Can I store fractional values (like 45.79) as a block value into a mifare classic card?

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could multiply your value first by 100 before storing and divide by 100 after reading. Think of it as storing the amount in cents instead of dollars.